# a countable open interval cover of the irrationals must also cover the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis

let $A:=[0,1]\setminus \Bbb Q$. Is it necessary for a countable open interval cover $(I_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ of $A$ also covers $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$, therefore, $A$?

I think this is true, due to the fact that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ are dense and each $I_k$ is open. But I have not found the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(-1,\frac 1 2)$ and $(\frac1  2, 2)$ cover $A$ but not $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ since $\frac 1  2$ is not in either one of these intervals..

Comment: Simpler: $(0,1)$ covers $A$ but not $0$ nor $1$.

Comment: thank you. Got it.